# Problem with writing mutation based on query result (type casting problem)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-composition-api, vue-apollo

So i do have a simple vue component. First of all i am fetching customer data using useQuery function. Then based on this data, i am rendering form.

```
 setup() {
   const route = useRoute();
   const id = route.params.customerId;
   const { result, loading, error } = useQuery(QUERY_CUSTOMER_FETCH, { id });
   const customer = useResult<Customer>(result);
   return {
     customer,
     loading,
     error,
   };
 },
```

Up to this moment everything works fine. I can edit returned customer data in my form. However I can't figure out a way to use mutation to save data. I thought that the best and the fastest way would be to cast my customer variable to an interface representing my input type like that:

```
    const { mutate: updateCustomer } = useMutation(
      MUTATION_CUSTOMER_UPDATE,
      () => ({
        variables: {
          id: id,
          input: new Object(customer.value as unknown as UpdateCustomerInput)
        },
      })
    );
```

Unfortunetly this solution is not working. Simply the value is not casted to a UpdateCustomerInput type. I am getting errors:

```
Field "__typename" is not defined by type UpdateCustomerInput.
Field "id" is not defined by type UpdateCustomerInput.
Field "created_at" is not defined by type UpdateCustomerInput.
```

Is there a way to cast the useResult returned value to a proper type to make mutation?

Comment: can't imagene the case when you need to use `new Object`. Try to avoid it